# What am I doing wrong in my AJAX code with my API weather app? It won't pull data from the site

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this as my ajax code, I'm trying to get weather data from openweathermap.

```
$("#sl").click(function() {
var city = $("#cityName").val();
console.log(city);
getID(city);

});

function getID(searchdata) {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q="+cityName+",ca&&appid=76e0a92437b70a4f70ae9ddc7132491e",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
      search: searchdata
    },
    success: function(cityID) {
        getinf(cityID);
        console.log(cityID);
    }
})
}
```

Additionally, this is my html code where the user searches for the city.

```
<form method="get">
     <div class="row col s10 offset-s1" id="citiesArea" style="display:inline">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="cityName" name="cityName" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="cityName">City Name</label>
          </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

When I inspect the element and check the console on google chrome, I'm being shown a "GET net::ERR_ABORTED" message. I'm unsure of what to do or how to fix it. I'm just creating a simple weather app where the user can search a city's weather, using openweathermap's API.

Thanks.

Comment: `&&`? try `&` instead - also, `getID(searchdata)` but `q="+cityName+"` - decide on a parameter/variable name and stick to it

Comment: Note: you can use `json` rather than `jsonp` as well, because openweathermap does send CORS response headers

Answer (score 0):

One issue for sure is the `&&` in `q="+cityName+",ca&&appid=` - change that to just `&`

The `data: {search: searchdata}` also seems redundant (ignored, actually)

Rewrite function as

```js
function getID(searchdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + searchdata + ",ca&appid=76e0a92437b70a4f70ae9ddc7132491e",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(cityID) {
            console.log(cityID);
        }
    })
}
getID('Vancouver');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And it seems to work fine